# How to fadeOut() both elements that are visible when clicking a button again after making them fadeIn()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="img"></div>
    <div>Gallery</div>
    <div>Stats</div>
    <div>Members</div>
    <div id="groupme">GroupMe</div>
    <div id="knd">K&amp;D</div> <!-- When I click this "button", the id "#kndpopup" becomes visible. --> 
    <div>Apply</div>
</div>
<div class="popup" id="guildinfo"> <!-- this is the second element that is toggled when the user clicks on "guild info >>" (if you look under the list section) -->
    <span class="info">Back to wars >></span>
</div>
<div id="kndpopup" class="popup"> <!-- this is the first element that toggles -->
    <h3>Knights & Dragons - Wars</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
        <li>1/7 80th place</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="info">Guild info >></span> <!-- clicking on this toggles the second element. -->
    <span id="previous">
    <a href="previouswars.html">Click here to see all previous wars</a>
    </span>
</div>
<!--End of popupwarsdiv-->
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#knd").click(function () {

    var KND = $("#kndpopup");
    var GUILDINFO = $("#guildinfo");

    if ((KND).is(':hidden')) {
        $(KND).fadeIn();
    } else if ((GUILDINFO).is(':visible')) {
        $(GUILDINFO).fadeOut();
        $(KND).fadeToggle();
    } else {
        $(KND).fadeOut();
    }

});

$(".info").click(function () {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();
    $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
});
```

I want to fadeOut() both `#kndpopup` and `#guildinfo` when I click the button after both elements are visible, but when it's on the `#guildinfo` page and I click on the `#knd` button it goes back to the `#kndpopup` page and then I have to click the button again to close it. How to fix this?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are trying to do, description confused me. Does this script work on 2 pages or 1 page with hidden elements?

Comment: 1 page with display: none; on 2 elements, one of them toggles when the user clicks a button, then inside that element is a <span> that you can click, then the second element takes the 1st element's place. If you click the <span> again you come back to the first element. But when the user sees the second element and clicks the button, I want both the elements to go back to being invisible. Understand it better now?

Comment: Can you post the html for this part, it's hard to tell which element is which from js only

Comment: Can you also update the question with which element click to do what? Kind of like the comment you had but more specific with the element id or class

Comment: I added comments in the code, hopefully you can understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok all i understood was

> but when it's on the #guildinfo page and I click on the #knd button it
>   goes back to the #kndpopup page and then I have to click the button
>   again to close it

Based on that

```
  $("#knd").click(function () {
     var KND = $("#kndpopup");
     var GUILDINFO = $("#guildinfo");

    if ((KND).is(':visible')) {
        $(KND).fadeOut();
    } else if ((GUILDINFO).is(':visible')) {
       $(GUILDINFO).fadeOut();
       $(KND).fadeOut();
    } else {
      $(KND).fadeIn();
   }
});

$(".info").click(function () {
    $("#kndpopup").fadeToggle();
    $("#guildinfo").fadeToggle();
});
```

Is that what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/58LYm/